# UIViewController view and subviews don't update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have spent the last few days trying to solve a strange problem concerning uiviews updates

I have an UIViewController (lets’ call it mm3ViewController) with 2 views (viewtop and viewbottom). (autolayout is ON, each view on half of the screen).

mm3ViewController is the parentviewcontroller of 2 childviewcontrollers called resultTopVC and resultBottomVC.

Those 2 childviewcontrollers are instances of Resultviewcontroller and child views are displayed in viewtop and viewbottom, using prepareview method of mm3ViewController:

```
//piece or mm3ViewController code
- (void)prepareviews{
    resultTopVC = [[resultsviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"resultsviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    resultTopVC.view.frame = _viewtop.bounds;
    resultTopVC.selectedview = SelectedviewisTop;
    [resultTopVC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.viewtop addSubview:resultTopVC.view];
    [self addChildViewController:resultTopVC];
    [resultTopVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    resultBottomVC = [[resultsviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"resultsviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    resultBottomVC.view.frame = _viewbottom.bounds;
    resultBottomVC.selectedview = SelectedviewisBotton;
    [resultBottomVC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.viewbottom addSubview:resultBottomVC.view];
    [self addChildViewController:resultBottomVC];
    [resultBottomVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

This part of the code seems to work fine.

Resultviewcontroller is a UIViewController containing 3 UILabels (Autolayout is ON).

I added a toucheBegan method to detect touches in any part of the Resultviewcontroller intances views and subviews. A touch trigger a method called buttontouched…

```
//piece or Resultviewcontroller  code
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self buttontouched:nil];
}
- (IBAction)buttontouched:(id)sender {
    ivc= [[inputViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"inputViewController" bundle:nil];
    ivc.selectedview = _selectedview;
    [self presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This method inits and display an UIViewController (inputViewController) that allows users to enter some data.

After data entry, when users are done… the inputViewController instance posts a notification (with some data wrapped in the userinfodic) that is used by the Resultviewcontroller instances (resultTopVC and resultBottomVC) to update their views backgroundcolor, labels, etc…and remove inputViewController instance

```
//piece of Resultviewcontroller code
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Notification managment methods
- (void) NotifEvalution:(NSNotification*)notice{
    if ([notice.name isEqualToString:kNotificationinputcancelled]) {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
    }
    if ([notice.name isEqualToString:kNotificationinputreturnobject]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];

        NSDictionary *dic = notice.userInfo;
        Selectedview caller = (Selectedview)[[dic objectForKey:@"caller"]integerValue];
        if (_selectedview == caller){
            NSLog(@"I receivers %@",[dic objectForKey:@"value"]);
            [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        }else{
            [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

The NotifEvalution method is called (NSLog tests work fine, inputVC is dissmissed)… but views and labels are not updates and I can’t figure out why!

I have tried different approaches and tests but I’m running out of options now…

Transparent UIButton on top of the Resultviewcontroller view hierarchy…instead of toucheBegan method don't solve thes problem

I have tested Notification or Delegate design pattern…

I noticed one thing: I can update views and labels with Resultviewcontroller ViewWillAppear method (outlets are set properly)… but I can’t update anything after inputVC is presented and dismissed…

My problem seems to involve that modalviewcontroller…

Do you have any clue concerning this problem and a way to fix it ?

Thx

Comment: At one point I even tested if the NotifEvalution code is running in the mainRunloop... It is!

Comment: I tried to duplicate your problem with a somewhat simplified version of your code, but it worked -- both views changed their background colors(I don't know if you expected that both views would change their color, but that's what happens in my test app). I don't see how at least, you would get one view changing to magenta unless self.view, for some reason, is not pointing to the view of your Resultviewcontroller instances. You should log self.view in the NotifEvaluation method, as well as in the viewDidLoad method of Resultviewcontroller to see if they point to the same thing.

Comment: I log self.view in viewdidload and NotifEvaluation...self.view is still pointing to the same object. I manage color using the selectedview property of resultsviewcontroller which is passed to the inputViewController at init, and returned back in the notification...

Comment: Is this log, NSLog(@"I receivers %@"... being called? Put a log in the else clause to , and see if that's called.

Comment: yes NSLog(@"I receivers...is called, and the else clause is called too

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't se how the view can't change color then, unless some code somewhere else is resetting the colors back to the previous values. You're not setting the background color in viewDidAppear are you?

Comment: yeap...it's driving me crazy! In viewDidppear I simply adjust some constraints. view background color problem is just a symptom...I can't update uilabels.text too (not in the sample code)

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Are you setting the colors in viewDidAppear? You shouldn't, because that will just override what you're doing in NotifEvaluation.

Comment: Nope I don't implement viewDidAppear

Comment: Ok. I don't know how else to help unless you can post the project somewhere so I can download it, and test it myself.

Comment: sorry, my bad... I implement a viewwillappear (some constraints updates) and I don't use viewdidappear

Comment: That shouldn't matter, as long as you're not resetting the colors there, I can't see why the colors aren't changing. Can you post your project somewhere?

Comment: Damn't You are right! I was blinded by Resultviewcontroller viewWill/DidAppear but the problem is mm3ViewController viewWillAppear... When the inputViewController is dismissed, the parentviewcontroller (mm3ViewController) viewWillAppear is called...that is where I call -(void)prepareviews to init and add Child ViewControllers!!! Damn It seems so obvious now! Thanks a lot for the help!